# Allauth email verification link still works after verification and doesn't invalidate

Tags: django, authentication, django-allauth, email-verification

I'm using allauth to handle my verification and I'm receiving verification emails to confirm signup. The verification email gets sent fine and works, but my problem is that even after I'm done with verification, the else statement in the html provided by allauth doesn't get triggered and the verification email still works and asks me to verify the user when I click on it, although it's already verified.

**email_confirm.html**

```
{% if confirmation %}

{% user_display confirmation.email_address.user as user_display %}

<p>{% blocktrans with confirmation.email_address.email as email %}Please confirm that <a href="mailto:{{ email }}">{{ email }}</a> is an e-mail address for user {{ user_display }}.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form method="post" action="{% url 'account_confirm_email' confirmation.key %}">
{% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">{% trans 'Confirm' %}</button>
</form>

{% else %}

{% url 'account_email' as email_url %}

<p>{% blocktrans %}This e-mail confirmation link expired or is invalid. Please <a href="{{ email_url }}">issue a new e-mail confirmation request</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

{% endif %}
```

Anyone face something similar or know a fix to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to go to your settings file to set cooldown time (the period after it the email will be invalid ) for the verification email

```
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS (=3)
```

you can visit https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html
for more configurations

Comment: Hey, this tackles emails not being sent multiple times, but doesn't tackle the problem of the link still being active despite being used, which is the question I'm asking. Any ideas about that? Thanks.

Comment: ``` ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS (=3)```
this will expire the confirmation email after period